# Suppose $\phi\in{Aut(C)}$ and continuous, why $\phi$ must fix $R$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $\phi\in{Aut(\mathbb{C})}$ and continuous, why $\phi$ must fix $\mathbb{R}$? I know that continuity is crucially important here, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: What is $C$? What is $R$? Are these the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ and the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: While continuity is crucial, your last sentence is incorrect: the ordered field $\mathbb{R}$ has no automorphisms at all! This is because the ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ is definable from the field structure: $x>y$ iff $\exists z(z^2+y=x)$.

Answer (score 6):

$\phi$ must fix $1$. By the fact that $\phi$ is an automorphism, it follows that it must fix $\mathbb{Q}$. A continuous function is uniquely defined by its value on a dense subset, so $\phi$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is uniquely defined by its value on $\mathbb{Q}$, which is constant.

Comment: Note that with a little more work, we can show using the same idea that the only continuous automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ are the identity and conjugation.

Comment: @NoahSchweber specifically, it is determined by where it maps the solutions of $x^2+1$, which is the minimal polynomial of the extension that produces $\mathbb{C}$ as an extension of $\mathbb{R}$. But it must permute the roots of the polynomial, and thus there are two possibilities: the identity and conjugation.

Comment: You don't even need to talk about minimal polynomials - it's easy to show that any automorphism has to send $i$ to $i$ or $-i$, and the set $\{a+bi: a, b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is thus determined by where $i$ goes and is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.